# Json reference exists validation

Tags: json, json.net, json-schema-validator

I want to know if it's possible to validate the existence of json reference using Json.NET.
An example :

```
{
  "objects": [{
     "$id": "1",
     "name": "obj1"
    },
    {
     "$id": "2",
     "name": "obj2",
     "previous": {
       "$ref": "1"
     },
     "next": {
       "$ref": "3"
     }
    },
    {
     "$id": "3",
     "name": "obj3",
     "previous": {
        "$ref": "2"
     }
    }
  ]
 }
```

Is it possible using Json.NET schema validation to check if the references exists, like if obj1 does not exists then raise error because it's referenced in obj2 as previous property and if obj3 does not exists then raise error because it's referenced in obj2 as next property.